# Are these correct initial thoughts to design a generic form creation tool? e.g. Google Form, Typeform

Tags: forms, database-design, architecture, business-process-management

Recently within our team, we were discussing to create a generic form creation tool which can create dynamic form with desired fields (text box, drop down, radio button etc. etc.)

the user can add as many as fields he wants to add (though normally it would not exceeds more than 20), can share the form with other users who can answer the questions or it could be simply just a data entry form for the single user.

We are trying to execute this step by step and in the first phase we would be doing something like:-

1. the user will have the option to create a new form.
2. there would be few predefined fields exists i.e. name label and textbox, address label and textarea, state drop down with some values, gender radio with options and some other sample fields.
3. above-displayed fields on the newly created form are just to help user to understand what kind of different fields he can create.
4. user can add/ delete fields, fields type would be textbox, textarea, dropdown, radio, multi-select checkbox etc.
5. after completing the desired fields user would save the form with "create form" button. entire data -field type, their values if it is drop down radio, will get saved in the database.
6. To access the form user will access the URL like form/5 and fill it and save.
7. We are creating a dynamic form and saving the form inputs as well.

**My Initial Thoughts**

8. When user will create a new form entire data would be saved as a single JSON object on NoSQL database.
9. when other or same user try to access the created from to fill the values same JSON object will be fetched and HTML would be created, In phase 2 we would might need a JSON to HTML converter program. but to keep it simple for now, we would just generate HTML from JSON at the client side. (web app/mobile app)
10. after users complete their inputs and save it. a new JSON object will be saved in another table named Records.
11. I read somewhere that for reporting and analytics purpose relational database is recommended so I was thinking of Maintaining all data in another relational database as well, duplicating our entire database. I am not sure about this and it could be a bad design.

This application can replace our several applications - some survey application, few data forms thus no. of records could easily reach into millions.

I am looking forward to any suggestion on the architecture/design and database type.

https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/finest-14-google-forms-alternatives-try/

**Update 1:** I agree with @SerejaBogolubov comment and not looking for the High-level/low-level design that includes Classes, Interfaces, their relations, functions and design patterns.
The question mentioned few steps and building block I would be using at the start and would like to know about various recommendations and thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I see no design ideas in your post. The place you gonna save (and format of the text file or whatever else) is secondary. Design is about interfaces, functions signatures, applied patterns, etc.

As a suggestion, you (obviously) have to separate form representation from the way it is rendered. Thus something like `FormRepresentation -> Html` appears. Then the question is how you gonna structure your `FormRepresentation`? I would suggest a (monoidic) binary operation: `FormItem -> FormItem -> FormItem` also known as kind of Composite OOP pattern; within associativity of the composition you might get parallezation for free and avoid performance headache, as well as keep your signatures really simple yet meaningful.

So, that was just a sketch. I would offer you to update your post appropriately such that design details (rather than implementation details) become clear.